# Hacer zoom en ImageView Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, eventos, android-imageview

Estoy trabajando en el zoom con gestos (pellizco) en una imagen.
La imagen si hace zoom, y también se puede mover atraves del Layout sin ningún inconveniente.

Tengo 2 problemas.

1: Es que al hacer la acción de zoom la imagen se comporta como si se anclara la esquina superior izquierda (guardamos el location X y Y) y luego realiza el zoom.

Esto ocasiona que cada vez que se hace zoom se tenga que deslizar para reubicar la parte que queremos visualizar; volvemos a hacer zoom y nuevamente hay que reubicar.

2: La imagen se puede mover a cualquier lugar, tanto así que en muchas ocasiones se desaparece de la parte visible de la pantalla y no se logra saber por donde quedo o donde anda, por lo que se tiene que refrescar para poder verla nuevamente.

Lo que necesito hacer es que se pueda hacer zoom pero sin anclar la esquina superior izquierda, sino mas bien como hacia el centro de donde se realiza el gesto con en la imagen. Y que no se salga del area de vision de la pantalla.
Comparto imagen para mejor comprension.

Ideas para revisar?

Lo que necesito: imagen #1

[image: Objetivo]

Lo que tengo: imagen #2

[image: Actualmente]

Les comparto el código tal vez me pueden dar una idea.

```
namespace PersonalA.Interface
{
    public class GestureRecognizerView : View
    {
        private static readonly int InvalidPointerId = -1;
        private readonly Drawable _icon;
        private readonly ScaleGestureDetector _scaleDetector;
        private int _activePointerId = InvalidPointerId;
        private float _lastTouchX;
        private float _lastTouchY;
        private float _posX;
        private float _posY;
        private float _scaleFactor = VarGlobal.gTamañoParaZoom;

        public GestureRecognizerView(Context context) : base(context, null, 0)
        {
            var ImageBitmapURL = GetImageBitmapFromUrl(VarGlobal.gImagenParaZoom); //Obtiene un Bipmap de un URL.
            Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(ImageBitmapURL); //Convirte el Bipmap a un Drawable.
            _icon = d; //Se usa el Drawable.
            _icon.SetBounds(0, 0, _icon.IntrinsicWidth, _icon.IntrinsicHeight);
            _scaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new MyScaleListener(this));

        }

        private Bitmap GetImageBitmapFromUrl(string url) //Procedimiento que convierte URL de Imagen a Bipmap Imagen. 
        {
            Bitmap imageBitmap = null;

            using (var webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);
                if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
                {
                    imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
                }
            }

            return imageBitmap;
        }


        public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
        {
            _scaleDetector.OnTouchEvent(ev);

            MotionEventActions action = ev.Action & MotionEventActions.Mask;
            int pointerIndex;

            switch (action)
            {
                case MotionEventActions.Down:
                    _lastTouchX = ev.GetX();
                    _lastTouchY = ev.GetY();
                    _activePointerId = ev.GetPointerId(0);
                    break;

                case MotionEventActions.Move:
                    pointerIndex = ev.FindPointerIndex(_activePointerId);
                    float x = ev.GetX(pointerIndex);
                    float y = ev.GetY(pointerIndex);
                    if (1==1) //(!_scaleDetector.IsInProgress)
                    {
                        // Only move the ScaleGestureDetector isn't already processing a gesture.
                        float deltaX = x - _lastTouchX;
                        float deltaY = y - _lastTouchY;
                        _posX += deltaX;
                        _posY += deltaY;
                        Invalidate();
                    }

                    _lastTouchX = x;
                    _lastTouchY = y;
                    break;

                case MotionEventActions.Up:
                case MotionEventActions.Cancel:
                    // This events occur when something cancels the gesture (for example the
                    // activity going in the background) or when the pointer has been lifted up.
                    // We no longer need to keep track of the active pointer.
                    _activePointerId = InvalidPointerId;
                    break;

                case MotionEventActions.PointerUp:
                    // We only want to update the last touch position if the the appropriate pointer
                    // has been lifted off the screen.
                    pointerIndex = (int)(ev.Action & MotionEventActions.PointerIndexMask) >> (int)MotionEventActions.PointerIndexShift;
                    int pointerId = ev.GetPointerId(pointerIndex);
                    if (pointerId == _activePointerId)
                    {
                        // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
                        // action pointer and adjust accordingly
                        int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                        _lastTouchX = ev.GetX(newPointerIndex);
                        _lastTouchY = ev.GetY(newPointerIndex);
                        _activePointerId = ev.GetPointerId(newPointerIndex);
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }

        protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            base.OnDraw(canvas);
            canvas.Save();
            
            canvas.Translate(_posX, _posY);
            canvas.Scale(_scaleFactor, _scaleFactor);
            _icon.Draw(canvas);
            canvas.Restore();
        }


        private class MyScaleListener : ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener
        {
            private readonly GestureRecognizerView _view;

            public MyScaleListener(GestureRecognizerView view)
            {
                _view = view;
            }

            public override bool OnScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector)
            {
                _view._scaleFactor *= detector.ScaleFactor;

                // put a limit on how small or big the image can get.
                if (_view._scaleFactor > 40.0f) //Max.
                {
                    _view._scaleFactor = 40.0f;
                }
                if (_view._scaleFactor < 0.1f) //Min.
                {
                    _view._scaleFactor = 5.0f; //Estandar sera lo minimo.
                }

                _view.Invalidate();
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: En android usamos esta clase , fijate si esta en xamarin https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ScaleGestureDetector.html  Si no encuentras esa clase busca el codigo como calcula el scale factor o en github liberias antiguas zoom para obtener codigo

Comment: Gracias. Acabo de actualizar los detalles.

Comment: Tu problema es el scroll gesture parece q estas moviendo la imagen, si solo scalas no tiene por que moverse, asi que para hacer scroll(mover la imagen ) es sencillo nada mas que detectar cuantos dedos hay con 1 dejas scrollear y no scalar, pero tambien pedes hacerlo mas complejo scalar y scrollear con 2 o mas dedos, lo cual tendrias que leer la matriz de la imagen osea su tamaño posicion , para decir hasta donde puede mover.

Comment: https://github.com/Only-IceSoul/JJLayoutPlus/blob/master/jjkit-layoutplus/src/main/java/com/jjlf/jjkit_layoutplus/JJImageScale.kt  linea 1699 , esta es tipo wasapp,  pero creo que tu problema puede ser el focus de la scala.